# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cada vez que ejecuto este código en python me aparece el error:

> *TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'*.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

```
def analizar():
    dic = {}
    fClasses = open(nomFileClasses,'r')
    lna = fClasses.readlines()
    for ln in lna:
        if not(ln in dic):
            dic[ln]=1
        else:
            dic[ln]=dic[ln]+1
    values = np.array(dic.values())
    std_desv = np.std(values,dtype=np.float32)
    return std_desv
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tengo algunas dudas sobre tu código, primero ¿qué es `nomFileClasses`?, de ser la ruta de un archivo debería ser una cadena y tener extensión,por ejemplo: `'nomFileClasses.txt'`. Por otro lado, en `dic[lna]=1` le estas pasando como clave al diccionario una lista (`lna`), ¿no deberia ser `dic[ln]=1`? En cuanto al error deberias poner el reporte completo, ¿en que línea te lo marca?El único objeto de tipo `dict_values` que hay lo tienes en `np.array(dic.values())` pero `NumPy` acepta esto, aemás lo produce una división (`/`) y no hay ninguna en el código.¿No se producirá en otra parte del código?

Comment: Gracias por responder FJSevilla. Con nomFileClasses ejecuto un método para abrir un .csv. He modificado el error del lna, ha sido un fallo al transcribir. Por otro lado, el error siempre me da al ejecutar este método. Te pongo el error entero:  File "C:\Users\C\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 72, in _mean
    ret = ret / rcount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'.

Comment: Acabo de comprobar que el error aparece en la línea     std_desv = np.std(values,dtype=np.float32)

Comment: Acabo de crear una respuesta,  el problema es que `values` no es lo que deberia ser , un array de enteros sino un array de objetos `view` y al usarlo para calcular la desviación estandar falla al intentar dividir un objeto de tipo `dict_values` entre un entero para calcular la media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `Python 3.x` a diferencia de `Python 2.x` el método `dict.values()` retorna un [`objeto de tipo  view`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) (`dict_values`) y no una lista. `NumPy` acepta `dict_values` a la hora de construir el array pero no obtenemos lo esperado (un array de los valores del diccionario). Para solucionarlo simplemente transformalo en una lista antes de pasarselo al constructor de `np.array`:

```
list(dic.values())
```

De esta forma si que se te creará un array de enteros sobre el que puedes calcular la std sin problemas.

El código es por lo tanto:

```
def analizar():
    dic = {}
    fClasses = open(nomFileClasses,'r')
    lna = fClasses.readlines()
    for ln in lna:
        if not(ln in dic):
            dic[ln]=1
        else:
            dic[ln]=dic[ln]+1
    values = np.array(list(dic.values()))
    std_desv = np.std(values,dtype=np.float32)
    return std_desv
```

Con esto deberia desaparecer el problema.

Como nota, si no me confundo estas usando el diccionario para contar el número de apariciones de las distintas cadenas que te retorna `readlines()`, puedes obtener el mismo resultado eficientemente de ser así usando [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) de la biblioteca estándar de Python:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def analizar():
    fClasses = open('nomFileClasses.txt','r')
    lna = fClasses.readlines()
    dic = Counter(lna)
    values = np.array(list(dic.values()))
    std_desv = np.std(values,dtype=np.float32)
    return std_desv
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Solucionado con lo que me has propuesto.

Comment: @Carla si la respuesta de JFSevilla ha solucionado tu problema, deberías de *aceptarla* haciendo *click* en el símbolo del *check*, a la izquierda de la respuesta, justo debajo del contador de votos. Es la forma de agradecerle su trabajo.

Comment: @Carla he añadido información a la respuesta por si te interesa/sirve usar `collections.Counter()`.  Saludos.